# Is "Attack on Titan" taking place in the past or in the future?

Tags: attack-on-titan

According to the prehistory timeline on [Wikia](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline#Prehistory),

> - **1003 B1**: As a young girl, Ymir Fritz gains the power of the Titans from an unknown source, becoming the Founding Titan. With her powers, she is able to turn her subjects into Pure Titans.
>
>   The Fritz family comes into power as the royal bloodline of Eldia, destined to remain unbroken for the next 2,000 years.
> - **990 B1**: For unknown reasons, Ymir Fritz dies 13 years after inheriting her power. Her "soul" is split between Nine Titans that are inherited by nine Subjects of Ymir, with the Founding Titan belonging to the Fritz family and the eight remaining Titans leading clans subservient to the Founding Titan. Those who inherit the power of the Titans are destined to die after 13 years as Ymir did due to a phenomena called the "Curse of Ymir."
>
>   The Nine Titans wage war against the nation of Marley, the dominant nation of the land, taking control of the continent and establishing the empire of Eldia. Eldia conquers countless other civilizations as well using Pure Titans as cheap weapons of mass destruction. This results in massive casualties and entire cultures being wiped out.
> - **Unknown**: Eventually, in-fighting breaks out between the various Eldian families for control over the eight Titans, but the Fritz family, using the power of the Founding Titan, maintains balance.
>
>   The Ackerman family, an Eldian bloodline resulted from the Eldian Empire's fiddling with the Subjects of Ymir, becomes the sword and shield of the royal family, remaining close to Eldia's king for generations.
>
>   Eldia becomes allies with Hizuru.

When the Titans arrived on Earth, what year is it?

Comment: When you say 'in the Past or in the Future', are you implying that AoT is set in a similar timeline as ours? Because it might or might not be the case. Although the first chapter's title seems to give a hint that the story is meant for someone 2000 years from now, which, if true, would mean that the story is set in the past. Might be relevant: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38213/what-does-the-title-of-first-chapter-of-attack-on-titan-進撃の巨人-shingeki-no-kyoji

Comment: Idk if dublicate really: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/when-and-where-does-attack-on-titan-take-place

Answer (score 2):

Let’s say in my opinion, *Attack on Titan* takes place currently in the year 2350...

Also, "**X**" stands for "when Titans arrived":

- Prehistory (Beginning of time until Zero Before X)
- 990 years Before X - the Great Titan War begins
- Zero years Before X - the Titans arrived

History (Zero Before X to 835 After X)

- 743 Years After X (2243) - the Great Titan War ends
- 835 Years After X (2335) - Eren and Mikasa are born in Wall Rose

The story of *Attack on Titan* (835 to 854 After X)

- 845 Years After X (2345) - Wall Maria is invaded by the Titans
- 850 Years After X (2350) - *Attack on Titan* takes place
- 851 Years After X (2351) - Wall Maria is set out for the First Time
- 854 Years After X (2354) - The Future of *Attack on Titan*

Answer (score 0):

It is the 'present' and the 'History of ymir' is the 2000 year old history.

> Spoiler
>
> ```
> Actually '2000 years in the future is the message of Ymir for Eren from the Titan realm
> ```

The Titans occured from Ymir herself (ie. Almost 2000 years ago)

I have read the manga, and is keeping up with it, so have tried to be spoiler free.
Just keep watching, and in case you want to read the manga, then the story of Ymir is somewhere around

> ```
> chapter 120
> ```

Comment: This may also help https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6920/what-is-shingeki-no-kyojins-year-zero?noredirect=1&lq=1