# Attack on titan chapter 79: possible flaw?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In Shingeki No Kyojin's latest chapter (chapter 79), beast titan throws a stone like he is playing baseball. But the story takes place in a time when baseball wasn't even known. These are the pictures:

[image]
[image]

Is this a flaw or a problem in the Japanese to English conversion? (Maybe the author did not intend baseball).

Or could it mean that Reiner, Bertolt, Annie and the beast titan are from a different time-line? (I don't think it's possible. If that's the case, they could have just used nuclear bombs instead of titans).

Comment: The answers to http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4615/7579 point out other things from our world that also exist in the world of Attack on Titan, so it's not impossible that baseball exists too, even if it's never been shown. After all, we know snooker exists in the world of Fate/Stay Night, even if we never see it.

Comment: It's also entirely possible that it's simply exageratted movements for the sake of inducing fear. Seeing this Beast-Titan doing something so deliberate conveys intelligence and a build-up of "What is it going to do?!" Additionally,  If you're going to throw something baseball-sized, it makes sense that baseball players throw it in the best way possible, so that could mean not that the Beast-Titan is throwing it like a baseball player, but that both of them are throwing it in an optimal manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is heavily implied, that world where events are set is our world in distant future. Remember castle Utgard? There was tuna cans with English writings only Ymir could understand.
It is just residents inside of walls being ignorant of possible past knowledge, possibly due to memory manipulation.

Comment: That brings another doubt. Why could only Ymir read english? Did the other recognize that its a tuna can?

Comment: I forgot that part.