# Attack On Titan Location

Tags: attack-on-titan

Do you guys know where the AOT location is? I tried using the map from a thread and my best possible solution was Australia or eastern Europe but I can say for sure. note the climate of Australia real doesn't suit the inside of the walls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When and where does Attack on Titan take place?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/when-and-where-does-attack-on-titan-take-place)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's the real world map but vertically flipped, (south) africa is Marley and Comoros islands is the paradise island.