# "Upside-down" map in Cowboy Bebop

Tags: cowboy-bebop

In session 18 (Speak Like A Child), a map of Japan, and the surrounding area, is shown on screen around the 10m40s mark. The orientation of the map is "upside-down" but the words are not flipped, indicating this was an intentional choice.

Is there any significance to the orientation of the map? Perhaps, in Japan, [South-up map orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South-up_map_orientation) is more common than in the west? Or was there a [geomagnetic reversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_reversal) in the Bebop universe? Or maybe the words on the map were also upside-down originally and it was flipped when it was localized for US audiences? Or am I just reading too much into it?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! FWIW, [this is the same scene in the Japanese broadcast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq91M.jpg), so perhaps anything regarding localization might be disregarded. There's a possibility that it's to imply that it is a fictional map/universe, like [the upside-down world map in *Attack on Titan*](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4615/2516).

Comment: There is no right side up in space tho

Comment: @кяαzєя Can you cite a scene in the show where that kind of sentiment is expressed? Or one of the authors, directors, or animators expressing something to that effect?

Comment: You have to think about it this way, in space, which direction is up?